# Python plot gray scale value vs pixel of an image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to implement [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Development) plot profile using python. Here, I'll read an image and then generate a histogram where image **pixel** is in X axis and image **gray value** in Y axis.

I've done the following so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = "default1.jpg"

img = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
pix = img.load()

data = list(img.getdata())  # convert image data to a list of integers
for x in range(0, WIDTH):
    for y in range(0, HEIGHT):
        if(x == 1000 and y == 80):
            print(pix[x, y]) # output is 145. I don't know what is it
```

I've this image [image: used image]

The output histogram from the ImageJ software looks like:
[image]

How to achieve that? any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Comment: @ThomasKühn, I tried with opencv to read the image and called `calHist` of opencv to generate the plot. But that doesn't show the desired output

Comment: Is your image in grey scale?

Comment: @ThomasKühn, I've given the image in the question. It's in RGB. I convert it to gray scale

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm starting to doubt that what you actually want is a pixel value histogram. At least your ImageJ doesn't look like that. (what does `Distance (pixels)` actually mean here?)

Comment: @ThomasKühn, the image size is 2304*1536. In the graph, in X axis the image width is given. In Y axis gray value on every pixel is shown.

Comment: If the x-axis shows the image width, you cannot be showing the value of *every* pixel. Is this an average over the y-dimension of the image, a certain row, etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177255/discussion-between-emu-and-thomas-kuhn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL images actually have a histogram method ([see the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/Image.html)), the output of which can be plotted with matplotlib:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = "image_histogram.jpg"

img = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
pix = img.load()

data = img.histogram()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

After figuring out in chat what the OP is after and looking a bit into the ImageJ code, here a python code that can re-produce the plot provided by the OP. Note, however, that this is *not* a histogram. Note also, that ImageJ can actually deal with complex regions of interest (sub-regions of the image), which my code is not capable of:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = "image_histogram.jpg"

img = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
pix = img.load()

data = np.asarray(img.getdata())
data = data.reshape((HEIGHT,WIDTH))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
reduced_data = data.mean(axis=0)

ax.plot(reduced_data)

plt.show()
```

The resulting image:

[image: result of new piece of code]

Comment: I can generate that. But it's not what I looking for. I want gray values of the given image in every pixel. Then plot the pixel and gray value in a histogram

Comment: Extraordinary man. Could you just tell me how did you generate that? The algorithm actually. That would be helpful :) Thanks

Comment: @Emu It's basically just two lines. The `getdata()` method returns a 1D `list`, which I convert into a `numpy.ndarray`. I then first reshape the data to the actual image dimensions (`data = data.reshape((HEIGHT,WIDTH))`) -- now it's a 2D array -- and then I compute the column-wise mean of the image pixel values (`reduced_data = data.mean(axis=0)`), which I then plot.